# Html window new page location not works location.href="mypage.html";...?

Tags: javascript, html

i need to open a new html page in the same page during the button click function.i have  tried this code but its not working.Whats is the error here .Help ,,Thanks in advance

My Button

```
 <input type="submit" name="login" id="ok" value="OK" onclick="viewgraph()"/>
```

My javascript

```
 function viewgraph()
        {
      alert("My First Jquery Test");

     // location.href('');
      window.location.href="graph.html";

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Snippet is working my side but, if it is not for you then ,

**Include**  `return false` in your function `viewgraph()`

or use `onsubmit = "return false;"`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/3aDhL/12/)

Comment: function viewgraph()
  {
     // location.href('');
      window.location.href="graph.html";
     return false;
    }
This also not works,,,,

Comment: Do you use <form></form> tag ?

Comment: Yes ,I have used form tag

Comment: if you able to remove form tag then, remove it, because inside form tag ,some browser force to POST the values and not redirect it!!

Comment: Your's welcome,if my answer works,then accept it !! :)

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't works because before redirection  you wrote alert, just remove alert function

Comment: try this: _viewgraph = function viewgraph(){...}_